# Apache2 installation error

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I am getting the following errors while installing `apache2` on Ubuntu .

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unknown group 'mlocate' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I think , I've messed up with apache-data .

Comment: Have anyone faced the same issue before ?

Comment: Please run and post the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade`. As far as I can tell, Apache has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you should uninstall it.
Type the following command in you terminal to remove all the packages associated to it
and after re-install it "it takes less than a 5 minutes".

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install apache2
```

In case you wanna go ahead check out this link: [install-apache-mysql-php-on Ubuntu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjr1Zryj6jbAhVCnRQKHWFHA3QQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04&usg=AOvVaw1wnNxusqubj9HKOOCMoVHz). Am currently relying on it to a little bit how these guys are configured and debugged. It will do you good I believe.

Comment: both these commands say 'Package ' apache2' is not installed '.

Comment: It means apache2 is not installed. What you do, type sudo apt-get install apache2 to install it.

Comment: after executing apt-get install apache2 . I get the above error , which I have asked in question.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for the error message comes up with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335538/unknown-user-in-statoverride-file), which suggests this is a dpkg problem rather than an apache problem. Further googling revelas that mlocate  reads  one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs  to  standard  output. See also updatedb. In other words, this is looks to be a database problem.

Adding the mlocate group (using the 'addgroup' command may help (although this should not be necessary on most Ubuntu versions) and have a look at https://linux.die.net/man/8/updatedb. This may point you in the right direction.

Comment: sudo sed -i '/mlocate/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride fixed my issue. 
Thanks all !