# MongoDB Community Server Installation Issue

Tags: server, mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB as per instructions provided in their [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

I am getting this error and I am unable to resolve this issue. Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated:

The commands I am running are as under:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
```

For Ubuntu 18 LTS:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

And Then:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

And Then:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

After running above mentioned command i get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl4 mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl4 mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/56.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 241 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown user 'mongodb' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown user in statoverride file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335538/unknown-user-in-statoverride-file)

Comment: did you fix this? I have the same problem