# dpkg; unrecoverable fatal error 'plocate'

Tags: bash

[image: plocate error]

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error. unknown system group 'plocate' in statoverride file; the system group got removed before the override,which is most probably a packaging bug
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown user in statoverride file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335538/unknown-user-in-statoverride-file)